# How do I persist the value of a property across page-refreshes?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have created a property in app.xaml ( Public Static List id {get set} )
Can i add Data (Eg: App.id.Add(user.id)) to it.

So that i can take the added data from the page and use it any navigated page (Eg: App.id[3]).

Initializing is the problem when page refreshed the data goes back to App.id[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternativ you could use the Singleton pattern here, this will ensure that the list is created and only one instance exsist.

In your App.cs file write the following:

```
    private static List<string> _id;

    public static List<string> id
    {
        get
        {
            if (_id == null)
                _id = new List<string>();

            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Frederik Singleton pattern Really works .. Thanks for answering

Comment: App.folderId.Remove(id[0]); An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code. When i remove data from persistent property it gives me this error because the list<strings> changes when i delete one of the item.

Comment: It depends on how you remove it, can you show some more code, else i can'nt help you?

Comment: foreach (string _str in App.Id)
            {
                if (navigationMessage.Contains(_str))
                {
                    App.Id.Remove(navigationMessage);                }                                                                                                           
            }

Comment: when the string is removed it gives that error and looping stops. so when removing list[2] from list of many. how can we deal with this.

Comment: Ok, it's because you can't remove an item from a list your are looping! Save items you must remove in another list and then loop this list and then remove from the App.Id list. That should Work!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, public properties defined in app.cs can be reached from all your pages in your app.

in your App.cs

```
    public List<String> id = new List<string>();

    // Call this method somewhere so you create some data to use... 
    // eg in your App() contructor
    public void CreateData()
    {
        id.Add("ID1");
        id.Add("ID2");
        id.Add("ID3");
        id.Add("ID4");
        id.Add("ID5");
    }
```

When you need to use it your can get the data from eg. the OnNavigateTo event handler

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Sets the data context for the page to have a list of strings
    this.DataContext = ((App)Application.Current).id;

   // Or you can index to the data directly
   var a = ((App)Application.Current).id[2];
}
```

Comment: but i want too call the property id to an page and add data from that page. like mainpage.xaml. and add data (id.add(y.userid)) problem is calling the property from app.cs gives me error.

Comment: Can you paste in the code that gives the error? I can'nt see why you can'nt do this.

Comment: Public static List<string> id {get;set;} which is in App.cs and i am calling it in mainpage.xaml.cs. I cannot call the id as (App.id.add(user.id)) in the page. it gives me this error (System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

Comment: Ok, it is because your not create a instance of your List, try to inserst "id = new List<string>();" in your App() constructor!, then it will Work :-)

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again i tried that  id = new List<string>(); its not persistent. if id is 1 and again 2 its forgets the 1.. id[0],id[1] instead it rolls back too id[0]=2;